# Iterative read of sorted files in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a list of files `1.dat`, ... ,`N.dat` in a directory which I want to read and analyzed.

I did the following

```
for f in os.listdir('.'): # read all the files in the directory
  if f.endswith('.dat'): # use only the ones with .dat as extansion
        print(f)
        data1 = np.loadtxt(f) 
        # some operations on each file
```

In this way, the files are taken in a random order, the output of print:

```
 6.dat
4.dat
8.dat
5.dat
13.dat
10.dat
1.dat
16.dat
20.dat
19.dat
```

So my question, how I can force the script to read the files in a sorted way? From file `1.dat` to `N.dat`.

Comment: could append the files to a list, then sort the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the full list of files and then sort them into the order you want.

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.dat')]
```

This gets you the list of `.dat` files. You don't need a full `for` loop and a list comprehension is faster.

The trick with sorting is that you need a key that will give you the proper order. In this case, convert to the numerical value for the key:

```
files.sort(key=lambda f: int(f[:-4]))
```

This will work *only* if you are sure that all the dat files have numerical names except for the last four characters.

Now you can process your list:

```
for f in files:
    data1 = np.loadtxt(f)
    ...
```

For a more complex sorting algorithm, I would recommend the library [natsort](http://pythonhosted.org/natsort/). Then your sorting step would look like

```
from natsort import natsorted
files = natsorted(files)
```

OR

```
from natsort import humansorted
files = humansorted(files)
```

The second version is locale-aware.

Comment: @ChristianDean. Thanks for the fix :)

Answer (score 3):

```
files = []
for f in os.listdir('.'): # read all the files in the directory
  if f.endswith('.dat'): # use only the ones with .dat as extansion
        files.append(f)
files.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split('.')[0]))
for f in files:
    data1 = np.loadtxt(f)
    # some operations on each file
```

Comment: No because `6` will not sort before `50` this way.

Comment: @Meccano thanks for your answer but as @MadPhysicist observe this script will sort in a wrong way such as `1.dat
10.dat
11.dat
12.dat
13.dat
14.dat
15.dat`

Comment: I have edited my post, I made a custom key function to take the numerical value of the number and not the lexicographic.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea. You just need to sort the files in the 'human-natural' way. There's a couple of different approaches;  pad them with zeros and then sort, for one. I like this one:

```
import re
def sorted_nicely(iter):
    """ Sort the given iterable in the way that humans expect; i.e,
    '2fast2furious' < '11fast11furious'
    """
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [ convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key) ]
    return sorted(iter, key=alphanum_key)
```

EG:

```
>>> print(sorted_nicely('a.dat 6.dat 4.dat 8.dat 5.dat 13.dat 10.dat 16.dat 18.dat 20.dat'.split())
['4.dat', '5.dat', '6.dat', '8.dat', '10.dat', '13.dat', '16.dat', '18.dat', '20.dat', 'a.dat']
```

Comment: What happens if you have both integer and text names? Pretty sure you will get an error if you have `['a.dat', '1.dat']`.

Comment: Nope. Added to the example to illustrate.

Comment: My mistake. BTW, this is a simplified version of what `natsort` library does.

Comment: You might want to turn that list into a tuple for robustness though.

Comment: Why? What does 'robustness' mean, besides 'I prefer it this way?' sorted() returns a list. Why create an extra data structure?

Comment: I was referring to the sort key, but you are right, it doesn't really matter here.

Comment: Ah, I see! You mean `alphanum_key =lambda key: tuple(convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key))`. Yeah, that would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your list of files using the `key` parameter of the `.sort()` function. But to sort the files based upon their numerical value, you need to convert the numerical part of the filename to an integer:

```
files = [file for file in os.listdir('.') if file.endswith('.dat')]
files.sort(key=lambda filename: int(filename[:-4]))

for f in files:
    data1 = np.loadtxt(f)
```

Comment: `filename[0]` is just the first character